# Use the new SQL Server 2016 FOR JSON PATH statement in a T-SQL query and return multiple rows (or resultsets) of JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server

I have setup a query that is similar to this sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/402f6/4

It returns a single JSON (a feature available in SQL Server 2016+) column.

As you might imagine, I am posting the JSON to a Web API endpoint.

However, the Web API endpoint limits the number of "rows" that can be submitted per request to 25.

So, in my example, rather than returning 1 row of JSON with 100 records I would want to return either 4 rows of JSON or 4 result sets of JSON.

Can that be done? How does it need to be refactored to do that?

Comment: Fiddles are good, but you need to post enough code in the question to make it stand alone.

Comment: You are returning a Json array. Are you able to deserialize it in the code to a list? Do you strictly need to do this in SQL?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, sorry but I don't follow.

Comment: @ZeinSleiman, right now just using the json fetch from sql is what I have been told to do.  I asked to deserialize into pocos but was vetoed.  Good question, though.

Comment: Please update your question to contain the minimum code required to understand your question (if for example the sqlfiddle site is down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with the following approach using `NTILE()` and `FOR JSON PATH`:

Statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 
      id AS [StudentID], 
      first_name as [FirstName], 
      last_name as [LastName], 
      email as [Email], 
      gender as [Gender],
      NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS GroupID
   FROM TestData
)
SELECT
   DISTINCT t1.GroupID,
   t2.Json
FROM cte t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT StudentID, FirstName, Email, Gender
   FROM cte
   WHERE GroupID = t1.GroupID
   FOR JSON PATH
) t2 (Json)
```

Result (using your test data):

```
GroupID Json
1       [{"StudentID":1,"FirstName":"Myrtie","Email":"mgunning0@bandcamp.com","Gender":"Female"}, ... ,{"StudentID":25,"FirstName":"Dante","Email":"dtoopeo@chronoengine.com","Gender":"Male"}]
2       [{"StudentID":26,"FirstName":"Hamilton","Email":"hginnanep@joomla.org","Gender":"Male"}, ... ,{"StudentID":50,"FirstName":"Enrika","Email":"ehayselden1d@weibo.com","Gender":"Female"}]
3       [{"StudentID":51,"FirstName":"Cirilo","Email":"cfrankcomb1e@blogspot.com","Gender":"Male"}, ...  ,{"StudentID":75,"FirstName":"Zeke","Email":"zleal22@eepurl.com","Gender":"Male"}]
4       [{"StudentID":76,"FirstName":"Todd","Email":"tscandred23@who.int","Gender":"Male"}, ...  ,{"StudentID":100,"FirstName":"Kristi","Email":"kpossek2r@wikispaces.com","Gender":"Female"}]
```

Comment: Zhorov, perfect...just was I was looking for.  Was not familiar with the NTILE function.